# Group By Sum without having direct Id

Tags: sql, t-sql

Having two tables, Orders and OrderDetails, set up like so.

Orders

```
 +--------------------+
 | ClientId | OrderId |
 +--------------------+
 |   Foo    |   1     |
 |   Foo    |   2     |
 |   Bar    |   3     |
 +--------------------+
```

OrderDetails

```
 +---------+-------+
 | OrderId | Sales |
 +---------+-------+
 |    1    |  10   |
 |    2    |  10   |
 |    3    |  10   |
 +---------+-------+
```

And I need a query without any Join that returns the following

```
+----------+-------+
|          | Total |
| ClientId | Sales |
+----------+-------+
|   Foo    |  20   |
|   Bar    |  10   |
+----------+-------+
```

Ideas?

Comment: Why can't you use a join here?

Comment: The data structure actually makes no sense . . . it looks like `orderID` is the primary key of both tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another option using cte.
But as Tim said, `join` should be the best solution

```
declare @order table (ClientID varchar(3), OrderId int)
declare @orderDetails table (OrderId int, Sales int)

insert into @order values ('Foo', 1), ('Foo', 2), ('Bar', 3)
insert into @orderDetails values (1, 10), (2, 10), (3, 10)

;with ctx as (
select o.ClientID,
        (select sum(Sales) from @orderDetails d where d.OrderId = o.OrderId) sales
from @order o
)
select ClientID, SUM(sales) TotalSales
from ctx
group by ClientID

-- With normal join
select o.ClientID, SUM(d.Sales) as TotalSales
from @order o
left join @orderDetails d on o.OrderId = d.OrderId
group by o.ClientID
```

You can change the `left join` to `inner join` if you want to have exact match.

Comment: If you check the execution plan, you'll find this is still executed as a join.

Comment: @BaconBits You are correct... I didn't check the execution plan, just do eliminate the wording `join`.  And compare the execution plan with `join`, it just the same...